# how to show the validation error below the input field in VF page

Tags: visualforce, validation, inputfield, regular-expressions, adderror

I have used the following code for the email validation and the validation is working fine but I would like to show the error like the the image. how to do that?

**My Code:**

```
 <apex:pageBlock id="myblock">
       Email  <apex:inputText value="{!email}" id="email"/><br/><br/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Click me!"  action="{!checkEmail}"/>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

**Apex:**

```
 public void checkEmail()
    {
        if(!Pattern.matches('[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}', email))
        {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 'Check your email')); 
        }
    }
```

My expected View:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="myblock">
    Email <apex:inputText value="{!email}" id="email"/><br/><br/>
    <div class="errorMsg">
        <strong></strong>&nbsp;{!emailError}
    </div>
    <apex:commandButton value="Click me!"  action="{!checkEmail}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Apex:

```
if(!Pattern.matches('[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}', email))
        {
         emailError ='Either first name or middle name must be defined';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the apex pagemessages functionality to achieve this - you'll have to roll your own to a degree, capturing the errors in controller properties and conditionally rendering markup to decorate the fields in error.

I wrote a blog post on this very topic some time ago:

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/field-level-error-messages-with_29.html

Comment: I got this error: Error: testController Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'for' at line 12 column 5

 for (testController wrap : wrappers)
       {
         if(!Pattern.matches('[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}', email))
        {
          wrap.emailError ='Either first name or middle name must be defined';
         }
 
       }

Comment: My COde is 
for (testController wrap : wrappers)
       {
         if(!Pattern.matches('[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}', email))
        {
          wrap.emailError ='Either first name or middle name must be defined';
         }
 
       }

Comment: That doesn't appear to be related to the question that you asked - its a regular expression issue. You should raise that as a separate question rather than tacking it on in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a new instance of the ApexPages.Message class using the following signature.

```
public Message(ApexPages.Severity severity, String summary, String detail, String id)
```

And then add this ApexPages.Message instance to ApexPages using  ApexPages.addmessage.

Note ID should be id of your field where you want to show the Error.

For more details refer

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_apexpages.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fapex_methods_system_apexpages.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: That link goes to "Introducing visualforce", could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0):

The standard email field can validate email format automatically, we can use that. 
For example, you can declare Account instance, then bind Account.Email with . If the email you typed is invalid, the error is 'Error: Invalid Email Address'. Then you can get email value in your apex code.

This is the easiest way i have known.